# trying to requery an already closed cursor using Autocomplete Text

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor
```

I have 2 activities and 2nd one is for viewing data from a database.

**First activity**
[image]

I can add data to the table without any error and I can view them from the a 2nd activity which gets all the data from a certain table in db, and list them in a listview using an array adapter. the problem comes when I delete a row, then view the list. then come back to the first activity, suddenly the error comes and force close....

This is my method for removing a row, I have implemented this in a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public Integer deleteCustomer(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(CUSTOMERS_TABLE_NAME,
            PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
```

this is how I get data from db in 2nd activity using asynctask,

```
Cursor c = db.getAllCustomerInfoFromCustomersTable();

        txtName  = new String[c.getCount()];
        txtTown  = new String[c.getCount()];
        txtTel  = new String[c.getCount()];
        txtId = new String[c.getCount()];
        c.moveToFirst();
        for(int a = 0; a < c.getCount(); a++){
            txtName[a] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("custname"));
            txtTown[a] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("town"));
            txtTel[a] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tel"));
            txtId[a] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
```

It works flawlessly.

This is the class I use in 1st activity for Autocomplete,

```
class ItemAutoTextAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private AutoCompleteDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    public ItemAutoTextAdapter(AutoCompleteDbAdapter dbHelper, Context context){
        super(context, null);
        mDbHelper = dbHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }

        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getMatchingStates(
                (constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));

        return cursor;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("custname");
        final String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        return str;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final String text = (String)convertToString(cursor);
        ((TextView) view).setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view =
                inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        parent, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

        // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("custname"));
        String town = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("town"));
        String tel = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tel"));
        selectedID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

        // Update the parent class's TextView
        //mStateCapitalView.setText(capital);
        eName.setText(name);
        eTown.setText(town);
        eTel.setText(tel);


        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I initialize it in onCreate method like this,

```
void setShit(){
    dbAdapter = new AutoCompleteDbAdapter(this);
    ItemAutoTextAdapter adapter = this.new ItemAutoTextAdapter(dbAdapter, getBaseContext());
    mStateNameView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mStateNameView.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
}
```

**Steps I tried**

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    dbAdapter.close();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setShit();
}
```

unfortunately they didn't work and the error keeps coming.

Again, 
 error comes when I delete a row in my table, then I press **VIEW** button then it shows the remaining rows in my table. then I press back button, app force close.
It will only happen if I edit or delete a row.

Edit method,

```
public boolean updateCustomer(Integer id, String name, String town, String tel) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CUSTOMERS_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(CUSTOMERS_TOWN, town);
    contentValues.put(CUSOMERS_TEL, tel);
    db.update(CUSTOMERS_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, PERSON_COLUMN_ID + " = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.ovnis.sscattered.billiingapp, PID: 30212
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ovnis.sscattered.billiingapp/com.ovnis.sscattered.billiingapp.CustomersActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@eb8fa5e
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3509)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@eb8fa5e
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6757)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6780)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3509) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

Comment: whats the full stacktrace?

Comment: @pskink edited and added it

Comment: are you using "managed Cursors" in your activity?

Comment: @pskink aside from the class, I use non

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#6749, this is your `"trying to requery an already closed cursor"` error, this is because `mManagedCursors` is non empty list

Comment: @pskink alright I will see for a possible solution. thank you